# What version of Aura am I working with?

Tags: developer-console, aura, developer-edition

I'm working in a [Developer Edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) of Salesforce and am experiencing some issues with Aura where components are not working as advertised.

I'm trying to figure out if I should [file an issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues) against the Aura Framework, but before I do that I'd like to know some information about the environment I'm working in (maybe I'm running an older release that has since been patched).

Aura has almost [4700 releases](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/releases) at the time of writing this post with no apparent/sane release cadence or versioning scheme.

**How can I find out what release of Aura I'm working with?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using it in Salesforce, you're using Lightning, a Salesforce-specific implementation of the Aura framework.

There's stuff in Lightning that's not in Aura and there's Aura GA components that aren't in Lightning.

The auradocs of your instance are the final word on what components and functions are available.

http://instance.salesforce.com/auradocs
Where instance is something like na1 or customdomain.my

Comment: While this doesn't explicitly tell me what version I'm working with and wouldn't really help when reporting issues, it at least removes any possible discrepancy between the documentation and the implementation.